# Rendering a block by logic within iteration

Tags: ember.js

I have a question:

Assuming I have a 'users' property in the controller which contains a list of user objects, then in the template, I would like to do something like:
(currentUser is just a property in the ApplicationController available in any template)

each u in users
  if u.id is currentUser.id
     renderThisBlock

Obviously 'if' helper can't work like that, it seems like Ember doesn't support block helpers so i'm not sure how this could be achieved,

please note that I need the condition to be per iteration, otherwise I would expose a method in the controller that returns boolean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `itemController` in the `{{#each}}` block

Just have

```
{{#each u in users itemController="App.TestController"}} 
  {{#if someComputedProperty}}
     renderThisBlock
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

You can define your itemController which checks the userId and currentUserId as

```
App.TestController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
   someComputedProperty: function(){
     var currentUserId = this.get('target).get('controllers.application.currentUserId');
     return (this.get('content.userId) === currentUserId)? true : false;
   }
});
```

Putting needs in itemController doesn't look efficient. So have your application Controller via `needs` in your context Controller (i mean the context of your template)

```
 App.AnotherController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
   needs: ['application']
 });
```

Hope this does your job done

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

There are two options:

A view can be created per such a section, then such method can be added to the view which will have a context per iteration

2nd is the solution above, one change though, in the iteration, should specified the short name of the controller and not the full name in the global namespace, such:

```
{{#each u in users itemController="test"}}
```

this binds to App.TestController.

Thanks!